# Wordpress 3 multi-site install

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, pound

Trying to figure out if this is possible... My company has a cms product that was written in Java and we decided to use Wordpress to run blogs for our clients. Obviously, Wordpress does not run on tomcat(at least not by default) so we installed Pound(http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) on our server and have setup any Apache and Tomcat on different ports. When "/blog/" is requested, the request is directed to Apache. This works fine but we would like to use Wordpress multi site so that we can manage all the blogs from a single interface. We would also like the url for every site to be "/blog/" example:

http://www.site1.com/blog/
http://www.site2.com/blog/

I'm thinking it would have to be done with apache??? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a WordPress StackExchange site winding it's way through the process at Area51. I invite any WordPress users/admins here to check it out and "commit" if you think it would be helpful. I did! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A.) use mod_jk (actually I think its mod_jk2 these days?) in apache.  You can configure it to proxy all url's by default back to tomcat and then have /blog handled by the local filesystem/mod_php mechanism.

Option B.) is to treat the php and java appservers as peers and put a http proxy in front of them that decides which url's get directed to which appserver.  You'll sometimes see loadbalancer vendors call this "url switching".

A has two parts, B has three, so knowing nothing else about your environment I'd say A, but if you have other reasons to justify the third component in house B could be appropriate.

Comment: I am actually using option B already, Pound is a reverse-proxy / load balancer. I'm just trying to figure out how I can make multiple blogs with WP multi site and all of them appear to be in /blog/ - In WP i can setup multiple blogs with either a domain, sub-domain, or subdirectory of the root domain that Wordpress was installed to. So for example, I could have http://blog1.domain.com, http://blog2.domain.com, etc. or http://domain.com/blog1, etc... Is there a way with apache to set things up in a way they http://domain.com/blog/ is equivalent to http://blog1.domain.com? Confuse you?

Comment: Sorry mike, I read the question wrong and it looks like Pound has grown up a lot since I last looked at it.   The answer to your actual question is a tricky combination of pound, apache-vhost, apache-mod_rewrite, and wordpress config.  I can't say off the top of my head what combo would work, just to trial and error around those parts.